# Unique "key" prop warning in render method - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

My app have a warning say that: `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of 'SortableTable'` Hear is my SortableTable file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {v4 as uuid} from 'node-uuid';

export default class SortableTable extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <table style={{width: '100%'}} className={this.props.className} id={this.props.id}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {this.props.headers.map(this.generateHeaders)}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.children}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    generateHeaders = (value) => {
        if (Object.keys(value).length === 0) return
        let sort, colspan
        if(value.sort) {

            let {query} = this.props;
            let nQuery, title, icon, colspan = 1;
            if(query.sort === value.sort && query.sortDirection === 'desc') {
                nQuery = Object.assign({}, query, {sort: value.sort, sortDirection: 'asc', page: 1})
                title = 'asc';
                icon = String.fromCharCode(0xe630)
            } else {
                nQuery = Object.assign({}, query, {sort: value.sort, sortDirection: 'desc', page: 1})
                title = 'desc';
                icon = String.fromCharCode(0xe62d)
            }
            sort = <Link to={this.props.link} query={nQuery} className="icon order active" title={title} data-icon={icon} />

        }
        let className = value.className ? value.className : ''
        if(value.colspan) {
            colspan = value.colspan
        }
        return <th className={className} colSpan={colspan}><span>{value.name}</span>{sort}</th>
    }
```

Can someone show me how to set key prop to resolve this warning?

Comment: Thank to @Pavlo, Tom Fenech and Oleg Kutsenko (why I can not tag all names), my problem is resolved! :))

Comment: For this question to be more helpful for future visitors, please accept the answer you like the most (there is a tick mark to the left of each answer). You will also earn some reputation from this.

Comment: All there answers here are correct. :D
But I still have one more question [relate to another file in the same directory of the SortableTable file above]. I don't want to publish a new question because it will similar to the main question - missing the key props. I posted the file content in [here](http://textuploader.com/5i66s) Please help me! I tried to add index parameter but it didn't work!

Comment: Feel free to post as many questions as you want. They may be helpful for someone else too; this is what this website is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to have a key attribute with a unique value. You can use [index, the second argument of `Array#map` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters):

```
generateHeaders = (value, index) => {
    // ...
    return <th key={index} className={className} colSpan={colspan}><span>{value.name}</span>{sort}</th>
}
```

Alternatively, if `value` object has a unique property like `id`, you may use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `<th>` element returned by `generateHeaders` needs to have a `key` attribute set on it, since you're returning an array of them from your `render` method.

The simplest way to achieve this is to use the index:

```
generateHeaders = (value, index) => {
// ...
    return <th key={index} //...
```

This will make the warning go away but it's better to use a unique property of each `value`, if one exists. This is because React uses the key to determine whether two items are the same. If you're using the array index and you insert a new value somewhere into the array, the indexes will change, causing the items to be re-rendered unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert key into th tag:

`generateHeaders = (value, index) => {
    ...
    return <th key={index} className={className} colSpan={colspan}><span>{value.name}</span>{sort}</th>
}`

Comment: I tried to set anything related to `Object` or `value` as the key in `td` tag but it did NOT work. I've tried yours and it's seem to be OK!

Comment: You should set only unique `key`. If you try set duplicate key, your next duplicate component will disappear